# How to get HttpOnly cookie

Tags: java, cookies, session-cookies, httponly, cookie-httponly

I need to *get the HttpOnly cookies set as Session cookie in my java code*.
To get non HttpOnly cookies I used Jsoup but now am stucked with HttpOnly cookies ?
**Note :**
Don't know if it matters but the site from which I want to get HttpCookies is developed in ASP.net.

Comment: If I use firebug I am able to see all the cookies, i.e., HttpOnly as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect Jsoup to make those available:

```
Connection connection = Jsoup.connect("http://example.com");
Connection.Response response = connection.execute();
```

...then use the `cookies` map on `response`.

If the HttpOnly cookies aren't there, you may have to read the contents of the URL directly (e.g., via [`URLConnection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) or similar) before passing them on to `JSoup.parse`, and look for the cookie headers in that stream.

---

Side note: To get a `Document` after connecting as with the above, without repeating the request, use `Connection#parse`:

```
Document doc = connection.parse();
```

I just mention this because you're likely to want the document as well as the cookies.

Comment: not working....there is no cookie header in body...not even the non HtmlOnly cookie is present in the body() method string

Comment: @SushilKumar: You may have to do something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16129860/157247

Comment: @SushilKumar: I just realized the `body` suggestion wasn't all that smart, the cookie headers are not (by definition!) in the body. So I've removed that. You may have to go down a layer, to `URLConnection` or similar.